# Using Informatica for one to one mapping for more than one source with different source structure

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

How to use a workflow for one to one mapping for more than one source with source name as parameter with different source structure in Informatica power Center? I have a data migration where I need to unload 800 tables into delimited text files.

Is there a way we can give the table name in parameter while running the workflow and the data will be unloaded to the output text file?

Comment: I have source as db2, Teradata and oracle. I need do run the export on quaterly basis. Not sure how to do it in informatica, we have can do the same in abinitio where we can create one mapping and pass the table name as parameter or pset.

Answer (score 1):

In Informatica PowerCenter, you'll need a separate mapping for each structure. Eg. if each one of 800 tables mentioned has unique structure and / or datatypes, you'll need 800 mappings. If the structure is shared across all 800 tables, one mapping can handle it. And if you've got 4 different structures, than 4 mappings will do.

If you do have 800 different structures, than it would be great to automate it. If I understand correctly, it would need to work like this:

http://powercenternotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/stage-mapping-generator.html,

but in the reverse direction (Table-to-File, rather than File-to-Table). If that's correct, feel free to contact me - I think I'd be able to prepare similar solution

Comment: Yes , i am looking for exactly the opposite, I want to automation where if i give teh table name the data is unloaded into Text files. We can use template for craeting multiple workflows but what if the number of tables are huge like 800 tables its will be very tiresome to create one mapping for each table and run it. I was thinking was automationg it somehow not sure how can we do it using informatica.

Comment: Do those tables share the structure? The answer to this question is crucial.

Comment: No, each table has different source and target structure. Only the transformation logic is will be same for all the tables which i am planning to read.

Comment: I could not find any such solution in informatica so i have created perl script to do the entire process, i think teh script is more flexible than using informatica for this purpose. Thanks all for your inputs.